# How to install python3 virtualenv and mod_wsgi on RHEL?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, rhel, selinux

On a rather conservative system (RHEL) I've decided to take the plunge, learn about virtualenv and migrate my wsgi application from the system's default 2.7 to 3.6. There are plenty of Python3 versions to go around:

```
$ yum search python3 | egrep '^python3[^-]+\.'
python34.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000
python34u.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000
python35u.x86_64 : Version 3.5 of the Python programming language
python36.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
python36u.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
$
```

I ended up installing python36 in a virtualenv. Everything works in the testing setup, so now it's time to install the proper apache module. However, virtualenv and mod_wsgi seem to be mutually exclusive because they have no version in common in python3:

```
$ yum search python | egrep '(virtualenv|mod_wsgi)'
python-virtualenv.noarch : Tool to create isolated Python environments
python3-virtualenv-doc.noarch : Documentation for python virtualenv
python34-virtualenv.noarch : Documentation for python virtualenv
python35u-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in
python35u-mod_wsgi-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package
                                    : python35u-mod_wsgi
python36-virtualenv.noarch : Documentation for python virtualenv
python36u-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in
python36u-mod_wsgi-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package
                                    : python36u-mod_wsgi
mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
python-virtualenv-api.noarch : An API for virtualenv/pip
python-virtualenv-clone.noarch : Script to clone virtualenvs
python-virtualenvwrapper.noarch : Enhancements to virtualenv
$
```

Note that the mod_wsgi packages have "35u" and "36u" version numbers whereas virtualenv only comes in "34" and "36". When I try to install any of the concurrently, I get screenfuls of conflict error messages.

Of course python27 (the default system version) is still around, so I tried creating a python36 environment using 27's virtualenv, but that fails, too:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.6 env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/base64.py", line 9, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
$
```

RHEL is what I've got to live with because that's what's running on some VM in my company's Intranet. At home I run Debian, issue-free. Also I can't use a different webserver because other people have different applications (PHP) on that server.

Answer (score 0):

OK, yet another question I'll answer myself. I find that having asked something in this forum always stimulates my own problem-solving skills.

Turns out I just had to install python36u which doesn't come with the "virtualenv" executable, but with the "venv" module, to be called like this:

```
python3.6 -m venv <env-dir>
```

Figuring this out was a lot easier than getting the environment to work under SELINUX because the security policy wouldn't allow Apache to load all the shared objects on import. Internet wisdom suggests to simply disable SELINUX which kind of defies its purpose  so I dug deeper and found out that I had to modify the shared libraries inside the environment:

```
find . -type f -name "*.so*" -or -name "*.so.*" | xargs sudo chcon -t shlib_t
```

Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

in Centos 7.7 installing python3-libselinux resolves the issue.

```
sudo yum install python3-libselinux
```

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer indicated, Red Hat added Python 3 (.6) to rhel7 with the release of 7.7. This can be used by installing the python3* packages with yum. Then there is no need to use the packages from EPEL.

Prior to that I used to use Software Collections which provided a separate installation of Python and Apache 2.4, although that has now migrated to Python 3.8 which is not well supported by a large number of third party libraries.

Regarding selinux, I found that adding a file context equivalency rule for each virtualenv works well and is robust in the face of relabelling or virtualenv updates. Just make the root of the virtualenv equivalent to / and you’re done.